# How can I use this LCD with Arduino?

Tags: arduino, lcd, display, arduino-uno

I found my LCD somewhere from some remote control. And as I am a beginner, I would like to ask you guys how could I connect these LCD with my Arduino Uno so that I can display the numbers on this LCD.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Without a datasheet you're going to have a very difficult job. (Please capitalise properly in your posts to improve readability.)

Comment: If the original device is not working already you can try to send all combinations of commands/data in Arduino loop and watch the changes on display. You can inspire with datasheet of different but similar LCD model for reducing combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing which display it is, it will be impossible to know how it works. There is quite a lot to it.

1. Supply voltage is unknown
2. Voltage of IO pins is unknown
3. How are the IO pins used to send data or command transactions is unknown
4. What kind of transactions or commands are needed to initialize the display and send pixel data is unknown.

The only way you can figure it out is to find the original device, measure the voltages the display supply and interface works with and then trying to reverse engineer what to send to the display by monitoring transactions sent to it.